# Two foreign keys on the same column from one table

Tags: mysql, innodb, relationships

i have a project table which has a `image_id` field and a `newsimage_id` field.

Both are linked to the image table. But InnoDB doesn't allow me to set a foreign key for
both fields to the same column (`id`).

Is there a way I can do this or is it not possible?
I'm using MySQL through MAMP.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I did it (MySQL 5.0.45):

```
ALTER TABLE `job_dependency`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`job`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`),
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`dependency`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`);
```

There are problems with ON DELETE CASCADE in this situation, so don't use it.

Comment: @prz: you did the trick! when i'm not using ON DELETE CASCADE it works. Thanks!!!

Comment: do you guys know what the issue is w/ ON DELETE CASCADE here?