# Two columns in same table and same foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm developing an application, actually a billing system. Here accountant can add invoice for a client.

I have two tables, `users` and `invoices`:

```
invoices (user_id, created_by)
users (id)
```

Invoices has two columns, `user_id` and `created_by`, I want both to be linked with `id` of the `users` table.

Already `user_id` has been added as foreign key. Now I'm trying to add `created_by` as foreign key. So issued following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `secureap_maind`.`users` (`id`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

And I'm getting an error message.

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`secureap_maind`.`#sql-3717_a323d`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-3717_a323d_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))

I'm not sure if I can add two columns as foreign key. IF possible, can you please advice to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638001/two-foreign-keys-on-the-same-column-from-one-table) implies that removing your `ON DELETE RESTRICT` clause from the `ALTER TABLE` statement *might* solve your problem.  Try running this query instead:

```
ALTER TABLE `invoices`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `secureap_maind`.`users`(`id`)
```

I am assuming that the `invoices` table was created using InnoDB rather than MyISAM, the latter which does not enforce foreign keys.

Comment: Perfect. Your advice worked for me.
And yes, I used InnoBD. As far I know foreign key relationship cannot be obtained using MyISAM.